# How to change ClientLogin to OAuth 2.0 in Google Cloud Print?

Tags: google-chrome, oauth-2.0, migration, google-cloud-print, google-client-login

Currently I trying to test the Google Cloud Print sample code in this link.
[Sample Maven project](https://github.com/jittagornp/GoogleCloudPrint)

And I unsuccessful to RUN it.
I encounter FileNotFound error.

Then I start to browse the request url 
[ClientLogin url](https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin)

This url redirect me to another documentation url ie:

[AuthForInstall Url](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps)

and I found out that GoogleCloudPrint was totally deprecated and no longer available. 
Now google using  OAuth 2.0.

May I know how can I change ClientLogin to  OAuth 2.0 in Google Cloud Print?
Thank you.

Comment: could you please paste some codes that you had tried?

Comment: I did post in another post. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058034/oauth-2-0-and-google-cloud-print)