# OAuth 2.0 And Google Cloud Print

Tags: oauth-2.0, apigee, google-cloud-print

I created a project called: "projectprint-123"

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient?project=projectprint-123

Credentials

> Web application 
>   Name : projectprint-123

What to ask can the 
1. Authorized JavaScript origins
2. Authorized redirect URIs
Put EMPTY? Because I testing localhost.
OK. I proceed to empty.

What is Oauth consent screen?
I only fill in Email address at this part.
OK. I proceed next.

Then I try

> https://www.google.com/cloudprint/getauthcode?
>   printerid=5e0db751-9498-677d-9cf3-3a7284978279&oauth_client_id=254414591833-7lg4a5nnnh009g9ccf613notg8vceunp.apps.googleusercontent.com

Fail:

> {   "success": false,   "message": "Unknown, used or expired token.", 
>   "request": {
>       "time": "0",
>       "params": {
>         "oauth_client_id": [
>           "254414591833-7lg4a5nnnh009g9ccf613notg8vceunp.apps.googleusercontent.com"
>         ],
>         "printerid": [
>           "5e0db751-9498-677d-9cf3-3a7284978279"
>         ]
>       }   },   "errorCode": 506 }

I using this APIGEE application to send

[https://apigee.com/console/others?req={%22resource%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcloudprint%2Fgetauthcode%22%2C%22params%22%3A{%22query%22%3A{}%2C%22template%22%3A{}%2C%22headers%22%3A{%22headers_name_0%22%3A%22Content-Type%22%2C%22headers_value_0%22%3A%22application%2Fx-www-form-urlencoded%22}%2C%22body%22%3A{%22attachmentFormat%22%3A%22mime%22%2C%22attachmentContentDisposition%22%3A%22form-data%22}}%2C%22verb%22%3A%22post%22}](http://APIGEE%20APP%20GETAUTH)

I appreciate if you can help.
Thank you.

Comment: actually , what you are expecting , an oAuth Token to print something?

Comment: yes,  an oAuth Token to print something

Comment: If you are not trying to register a new google-cloud-printer, this is not the way to get the OAuth authorization token.
The /getauthcode URL is only used as during the printer registration process.